# string.slice() not working on Server Side Javascript in ASPx

Tags: javascript, asp.net, string, server-side, trim

I am writing **server side javascript code in aspx** to pull out the 7 columns from CSV files which may or may not use quotes to enclose the data, depending on the file.

Currently, I am working on the code to remove the commas using javascript's string.sllice() for the first column, but is is returning an empty string.

Here is a sample line from the file. This is public info.

12/6/2017,8:30 AM,2013FA000060,In RE: the Support of: D.D.K. and A.P.C.,MH,Motion hearing,"Grill, Leo",State of Wisconsin,"Vesely, Tori A; Lawton, Mark David";

In working with my Regular expression based code for the first column, I have the correct expected string data for *strTemp* prior to the offending code:

12/6/2017,

Here is the code to remove the  comma at the end:

```
cleanData = strTemp.slice(0, -1);   // remove last 1 character
```

I have verified that strTemp is correct right before this statement is executed to make sure the string var assignments are not the problem (*as seen above*).

The expected result should be *strTemp* data without the comma at the end:

12/6/2017

I receive no errors. Just an empty string.

Comment: "I am working on the code to remove the commas using javascript's string.splice()" - which is it, `slice()` or `splice()`? You refer to both

Comment: what's wrong with using strTemp.split(','); so you don't have to worry about extracting the comma from the end all together??

Comment: take a look at papaParse.js which is great at figuring out which delimiters are used. No need to re-invent the wheel. Will also provide error feedback

Comment: This may be used for content which may have commas in it, so split would not work. I had considered that to separate all of the columns, but there may be commas in the text too. =(

Comment: PapaParse? Will this work with server side asp code? If so, how would I include the script in the ASP page?

Comment: slice - not splice, brain error

Comment: Thanks guys!
I really appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it looks like the data coming from the regular expression execute is not a string. Once I cast it to string it worked

cleanData = strTemp.toString().slice(0, -1);

I really do NOT like working with weakly typed languages!!